# Chrome (not Chromium) Application name changed after disconnecting it from Google Account

Tags: google-chrome, launcher, chromium, dock

With a clean Ubuntu 16.04 install, I first connected Chromium to my Google account, I have the Synology Note Station Chrome app, so I signed into my NAS and my notes synced.

After this I installed Chrome (via apt-get install google-chrome-stable) and connected it to my google account, without thinking I started the Synology Note Station app from Chrome and it asked me to sign in again so I did.

Next I unlinked Chromium from my Google account, this caused the Chrome browser to appear as "Synology Note Station" instead of "Chrome" in my applications and dock. The icon is still the Chrome icon, I can find it by searching my apps for "Chrome", but it appears under my apps as "Synology Note Station".

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome, it still showed up as "Synology Note Station". Next I purged Chrome and reinstalled it with no difference. Finally I uninstalled the Synology Note Station app, unlinked Chrome from my Google account, purged Chrome, rebooted and reinstalled it and it still shows up as "Synology Note Station".

I've only been using Linux for a few months, so I'm not sure where to even start with this.

Chrome still works fine, it just bothers me that the name is wrong.

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: does chrome work as normal once launched? And can you see it in /usr/share/applications ?